Using FieldMask for DocumentAI inner fields in Google Java SDK
I'm looking at the Google DocumentAI SDK and I'm trying to filter out an "inner" field, specifically the BoundingPoly.vertices field from all objects.
The bounding poly is part of the Layout object which is itself part of the Page object but also Block, Paragraph and many other objects. I'm looking to filter out the vertices field from everywhere because the BoundingPoly also comes with the normalizedVertices field which is equivalent and I don't need both of them (each document shard I receive contains 8000 x2 or those objects and JSON parsing is the slowest part of the process in general).
I tried something like this
FieldMask.Builder bldr = FieldMask.newBuilder();
for (Descriptors.FieldDescriptor fieldDescr : BoundingPoly.getDescriptor().getFields()) {
  if("vertices".equalsIgnoreCase(fieldDescr.getName()))
    continue;
  bldr.addPaths("bounding_poly." + fieldDescr.getJsonName());
}

but the API complains with Only top level document and page fields are supported in field mask, got bounding_poly.normalizedVertices which means that it can either accept field on the Document or on the Page object.
Is there another way of doing this? I don't want to filter the JSON file or some weird thing like that, I'd expect the API to support this.

drive-by comment with apologies. FieldMasks are inclusive not exclusive. Corollary you need to define what you want not what you don't want. Also, the FieldMask must be defined from the document root (I think Page) in your case.

Yes, I also tried to define fields like pages.layout.bounding_poly.normalized_vertices and leave the vertices out of the list but it still didn't accept it. It seems that once you go one object further than a Page field it won't allow it.

I don't use Document AI and it's difficult to build a repro. Can you add clarification of "it won't allow it" to your question. What output exactly do you get when you try to run the code with the FieldMask rooted from e.g. pages.layout.bounding_poly? Have you tried pages.layout.boundingPoly?

The part in italics: Only top level document and page fields are supported in field mask, got bounding_poly.normalizedVertices

Even if rooted from the page: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Only top level document and page fields are supported in field mask, got pages.layout.bounding_poly.normalizedVertices and it's the same even if I do normalized_vertices instead.

Hi @PentaKon, Could you check these similar stack link1 and link2 for your reference ? Also check this documentation for GCS Output Config and let me know if this helps you or not ?

None of the above is related to what I'm asking unfortunately
